# Mask not working in corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

All I trying to do is to have part of my image showing and have the rest hidden. In the end I'll have the showing part clickable and I am having some trouble getting the mask to work.

Here is my code:

```
streams[0] = widget.newButton
  {
      width = display.contentWidth,
      height = display.contentHeight,
      left = 0,
      top = 0,
      defaultFile = "Images/hydro_screen/hy_screen_river1.png"
  }

  local mask = graphics.newMask( "Images/hydro_screen/hy_screen_river1_mask.png" )
  local xScale = streams[0].width/2400
  local yScale = streams[0].height/1600

  streams[0]:setMask( mask )
  streams[0].maskScaleX = xScale
  streams[0].maskScaleY = yScale
  streams[0].maskX = streams[0].width/2  
  streams[0].maskY = stream[0].height/2
```

I've been playing with the numbers and no matter what I do my river is completely hidden. Does anybody have any recommendations?

Here are my two images I am working with. They are both the same size.

[image: River that appears on top of a background]
[image: mask to only make the blue part of the river file clickable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your mask is valid.  The mask must have at least 3 pixels of black on all four sides.  See:  http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/media/imageMask/index.html

Yours does not.  The top and bottom edges have white pixels along the edges.  This could be causing your issue.